# What is / are the major properties of a "log log plot"?

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions

The only log chart I have tried before was a log scale on the $y$-axis, so that exponential growth of a number (such as stock prices) on the $y$-axis becomes a straight line.

But today I know there is something called a "$\log \log$-plot", meaning both the x and y axis has a log scale.

(Edit: the following about polynomial is not correct. It is only true for "power functions". See the info in the answers). It seems the plot can make any "polynomial function"

$$ y = a_0 x^n + a_1 x^{n-1} + ... + a_n, $$

become a straight line, probably with the slope of a number $a_0n + a_1(n-1) +  a_2(n-2) + \ldots $

such as

$$ y = 8x^3 + 7x^2 + 6x + 5, $$

then the slope of the line is $8 \times 3 + 7 \times 2 + 6 \times 1 + 0 = 44$ on the $\log \log$-plot. (It feels weird that the $ x^3 $ is usually seen as powerful, but the 8 makes the slope much bigger than the effect of the $ x^3 $).  Are there other use or major properties of a $\log \log$-plot?

Comment: This isn't right though. The log-log plot of $y=8x^3$ would have a slope of 3; e.g., $\log y =3 \log x + \log 8$. Given $y=p(x)$ where $p$ is a polynomial, the asymptotic slope is the degree of $p$; the lower-ordere terms vanish.

Comment: I'm curious why someone thought this question deserved a downvote. It proposes a hypothesis that turned out to be false, but it does so clearly and readably -- and the asker has obviously _thought about_ the question even though he reached wrong conclusions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A double-log coordinate system makes **power functions**:
$$ y = ax^b $$
become straight lines. The parameter $b$ determines the visual slope on the line; $a$ determines its location (up/down).

Taking the logarithm on both sides of $y=ax^b$ gives you $$\log y = \log a + b\log x.$$ You can now set $y'=\log y$ and $x'=\log x$ for physical plotting distances and get
$$y' = bx' + \log a$$

---

Polynomials with more than one term are not straight lines in such a coordinate system. (But they have straight *asymptotes* corresponding to their first and last nonzero terms).

Comment: is the power function related to fractals or are there common practical use of it (it is said to describe nature in a computer algorithm book by Sedgewick)

Comment: @太極者無極而生: Fractals often follow [power laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law) which are described by power functions. So, for example, you can estimate a fractal dimension by plotting counts at different scales in a log-log coordinate system and fitting with a line.

Comment: so you don't take y' = log y and x' = log x and make the original formula $ y' = a (log x) ^ b $ and therefore $ y' = a x' ^ b $ and $ y' = ab x' $ ?

Comment: oh... taking log on both sides is not changing the coordinate system... it is just something you can do to any equations (do the same thing to both sides and still maintain their equality)

Comment: @太極者無極而生 Correct.

Comment: @太極者無極而生 A more systematic procedure for "I have this strange equation and wonder how it would look in a log-log" coordinate system would be to substute $e^{x'}$ for $x$ and $e^{y'}$ for $y$ (the _inverse function_ of the logarithm -- this gets you, in this case, $$ e^{y'} = a (e^{x'})^b $$ at which point you might again get the idea of taking the logarithm on both sides to make it into a more familiar form. Of course if you do that with something that doesn't _actually_ look nice in log-log coordinates you may just get some horrible equation that you can't do anything with.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't right though, OP.  Given $y=p(x)$ where $p$ is a polynomial, the asymptotic slope of the log-log plot is the degree of $p$; the lower-order terms vanish in their effect on the log-log plot for $x$ large. The log-log plot of $y=8x^3$ would have a slope of 3; e.g., $\log y =3 \log x + \log 8$. The log-log plot of $y=8x^3+7x^2+6x+5$ would be a curve above the line $\log y = 3 \log x+ \log 8$ but would converge to this line for large $x$.

In fact, given $y = a_rx^r + \sum_{i=0}^{r-1}a_ix^i$, the log-log plot of $y$ versus $x$ would converge for large $x$ to the line $\log y = r \log x+ \log a_r$.